# How to store the communication frame

Tags: c++

I’m a bad programmer and I have a question.

For example, each frame of communication has valueA (8bit), valueB(8bit) ,valueC(8bit) ,valueD(8bit), a total of 32 bits.

Now the number of frames sent is uncertain. I want to form a sequential array of valueB and valueD in each frame sent. For example, if 3 frames are sent sequentially,

So my one-dimensional array is (valueB, valueD, valueB, valueD, valueB, valueD) at once. What is the best method? What about caching? How to use that? C++

I don,t know if I can use for method twice

Comment: Also one question per post.

Comment: _"What is the **best** method ?"_ The "best" is closely dependent to the criteria of interest. Most of the time, there is no absolute/generic best method.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the simplest method would be to define a type representing a valueB/valueD pair:

```
class ValueBAndD
{
public:
   ValueBAndD() : _valueB(0), _valueD(0) {/* empty */}
   ValueBAndD(uint8_t b, uint8_t d) : _valueB(b), _valueD(d) {/* empty */}

   uint8_t _valueB;
   uint8_t _valueD;
};
```

... then you can simply declare a `std::vector<ValueBAndD>` somewhere and add values to it with `emplace_back()` as necessary:

```
std::vector<ValueBAndD> myVec;
myVec.emplace_back(1,2);
myVec.emplace_back(3,4);
// etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How about if i use the cache to store the value to one array.

Comment: I don't know what "the cache" is referring to in this context.  If you are referring to the caches on your CPU, those are always used automatically, you don't need to do anything explicit in your code to make use of them.